# Having trouble with Angular.js routes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

below is what my app.js and controllers.js files look like:

```
angular.module('RayAuth', ['RayAuth.filters', 'RayAuth.services', 'RayAuth.directives']).
  config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/index.html',
        controller: IndexCtrl
      }).
      when('/users', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/users.html',
        controller: UserCtrl
      }).
      when('/controlpanel', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/controlpanel.html',
        controller: ControlCtrl
      }).
      when('/modules/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/modules.html',
        controller: ModuleCtrl
      }).
      when('/resources/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/resources.html',
        controller: ResourceCtrl
      }).
      when('/privileges/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/privileges.html',
        controller: PrivilegeCtrl
      }).
      when('/roles/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/roles.html',
        controller: RoleCtrl
      }).
      when('/userroles/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/userroles.html',
        controller: UserRoleCtrl
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }]);
```

and this is my controllers.js:

```
'use strict';

function IndexCtrl() {
    IndexCtrl.$inject = [];
}

function UserCtrl() {
    UserCtrl.$inject = [];
}

function ControlCtrl() {
    ControlCtrl.$inject = [];
}

function ModuleCtrl() {
    ModuleCtrl.$inject = [];
}

function ResourceCtrl() {
    ResourceCtrl.$inject = [];
}

function PrivilegeCtrl() {
    PrivilegeCtrl.$inject = [];
}

function RoleCtrl() {
    RoleCtrl.$inject = [];
}

function UserRoleCtrl() {
    UserRoleCtrl.$inject = [];
}
```

i have added the `ng-app` and `ng-view` to my index file but when i load it in the browser it keeps redirecting to `http://localhost/` instead of `http://localhost/ray-auth/` what am i doing wrong here? can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
angular.module('RayAuth', ['RayAuth.filters', 'RayAuth.services', 'RayAuth.directives']).
  config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/index.html',
        controller: IndexCtrl
      }).
      when('/users', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/users.html',
        controller: UserCtrl
      }).
      when('/controlpanel', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/controlpanel.html',
        controller: ControlCtrl
      }).
      when('/modules/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/modules.html',
        controller: ModuleCtrl
      }).
      when('/resources/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/resources.html',
        controller: ResourceCtrl
      }).
      when('/privileges/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/privileges.html',
        controller: PrivilegeCtrl
      }).
      when('/roles/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/roles.html',
        controller: RoleCtrl
      }).
      when('/userroles/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/userroles.html',
        controller: UserRoleCtrl
      });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }]);
```

I have removed the otherwise , which actually tells it to redirect to '/' in all other cases.

Also on a side note,

```
function PrivilegeCtrl() {

}
PrivilegeCtrl.$inject = [];
```

As shown above, the inject should be done outside the controller.

Comment: ok thanks. it works now but the navigation is messed up. i have the navigation bar on the template page but when i click on users, when i am on the users page and want to click on roles its like 'users/roles/ instead of 'roles/'

Comment: @hilarl : Sorry I dont understand what you are trying to say. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="RayAuth">
```